# How to validate postman response body for dynamic values

Tags: variables, postman

I have a response body with following fields and these values are coming from DB and values changes every time we hit send button(values are dynamic). How can I validate the response in the postman test script.
Please help.
Thanks!

```
{
“memberId”: 123,
“email”: “abc@gmail.com”,
“memberStatusCode”: “CANCEL”,
“isActive”: true,
“joinDate”: “2021-04-09T08:09:08.32+00:00”,
“cancelDate”: “2021-04-09T08:10:03.653+00:00”,
“effectiveCancelDate”: “2021-05-09T08:10:03.653+00:00”,
“primaryCustomIdentifier”: “pendingcancelQA040921”
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with variables but as the values changes each time (as new users joining in) the tests fail

Comment: As the variables change each time you're not going to be able to do many assertions (`pm.expect(a).to.equal(a)`) on the actual values. You could test for other things like the structure, dataTypes, property names etc.

Comment: @DannyDainton Sorry i just saw dynamic and thought its about postman dynamic varible :D